# Scroll page to section ID on Radio Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to scroll the page to a specific section IDs depending on radio click.

Currently I am getting the error of: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

I thought I had it defined, I can use `console.log(this.id);` and get the correct value, but must have something around the wrong way!

Here is the JSfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/yxjy2u3p/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your html as follows:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="selection">1
<input type="radio" value="2" name="selection">2
<input type="radio" value="3" name="selection">3
<input type="radio" value="4" name="selection">4
```

You should use `value` attribute here instead of `id`, as you are using same ids for the sections. You should have unique ids, as it might cause confusion and problems. Now ids `1,2,3,4` only belong to the sections.

And in code to scroll to, you need to append `"#"` before the selecting of the section id you want to scroll to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=selection]').change(function()
    {
        $('html,body').animate(
        {
                scrollTop: $('#'+this.value).offset().top
      }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in that place, where you're trying to get the element. You write:

```
scrollTop: $(this.id).offset().top
```

And it will be the same as (I used "1" just for example, it can be "2" or "3" and so on):

```
scrollTop: $("1").offset().top
```

But in jquery we select by id like this:

```
$("#1")
```

So finally you only need to add `#` before provided variable:

```
scrollTop: $("#"+this.id).offset().top
```

Here is the fiddle without that error: https://jsfiddle.net/yxjy2u3p/1/